# Multiple to One SQL references without repeating any of the "one" entries

Tags: sql, join

So ive been poking around on here for a while, but havent been able to figure this out yet and have finally given up trying the guess method and am asking for help.

I have three tables in a database.  One tracks invoice level detail (customer, shipping charge for the invoice, payments ect.) another tracks line item detail (Items on the order, costs/ item, selling price/ item ect.) and the last table holds data on the shipment EG: tracking numbers, cost of the shipping ect.

so i have:

```
CustomerInvoice
CustomerInvoiceDetail
Shipment
```

I am trying to end up with a single select statement that joins these tables but does not repeat any invoice detail when matched against the shipment table.  CustomerInvoice has a one to many relationship with both CustomerInoiceDetail and Shipment, because an order can have multiple lineitems AND multiple shipments.

so far i have:

```
SELECT     
    CustomerInvoice.InvoiceCode, CustomerInvoiceDetail.ItemCode,
    CustomerInvoiceDetail.LineNum, Shipment.SourceDocument, 
    Shipment.TrackingNumber, CustomerInvoiceDetail.ActualCost, 
    CustomerInvoiceDetail.ExtActualCost, Shipment.Freight AS FreightCost,
    CustomerInvoiceDetail.SalesPrice, CustomerInvoiceDetail.ExtPrice, 
    CustomerInvoiceDetail.SalesTaxAmount, CustomerInvoice.Freight, 
    CustomerInvoice.FreightTax

FROM         
    CustomerInvoiceDetail LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  Shipment RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  CustomerInvoice 
    ON Shipment.SourceDocument = CustomerInvoice.SourceInvoiceCode 
    ON CustomerInvoiceDetail.InvoiceCode = CustomerInvoice.InvoiceCode
;
```

Ideally we need the result to display a row with shipment and order level detail, and no invoice line item detail, and then all of the invoice line item detail below.  I was thinking this could be done by doing an inner join Invoice to shipment but then don't know how to further included every line from invoice detail without having it join to the other data on any criteria.  In the end what is needed is to avoid having the end result contain the same monetary figures multiple times for any order.

for reference i re-wrote the query submitted by Gordon Linoff in full syntax and ran it. It oddly enough only has an issue with the case statement currently.  This is what it looks like:

```
`--REFERENCE JOIN STATEMENT          
SELECT CustomerInvoice.InvoiceCode, NULL as ItemCode,
       NULL as LineNum, Shipment.SourceDocument, 
       Shipment.TrackingNumber, NULL as ActualCost, 
       NULL as ExtActualCost, Shipment.Freight AS FreightCost,
       NULL as SalesPrice, NULL as ExtPrice, 
       NULL as SalesTaxAmount, CustomerInvoice.Freight, 
       CustomerInvoice.FreightTax
FROM Shipment RIGHT OUTER JOIN
     CustomerInvoice
    ON Shipment.SourceDocument = CustomerInvoice.SourceInvoiceCode 
union all
select CustomerInvoice.InvoiceCode, CustomerInvoiceDetail.ItemCode,
       CustomerInvoiceDetail.LineNum, NULL as SourceDocument, 
       NULL as TrackingNumber, CustomerInvoiceDetail.ActualCost, 
       CustomerInvoiceDetail.ExtActualCost, NULL AS FreightCost,
       CustomerInvoiceDetail.SalesPrice, CustomerInvoiceDetail.ExtPrice, 
       CustomerInvoiceDetail.SalesTaxAmount, CustomerInvoice.Freight, 
       CustomerInvoice.FreightTax
from CustomerInvoice join
     CustomerInvoiceDetail
     on CustomerInvoice.InvoiceCode = CustomerInvoiceDetail.InvoiceCode
order by InvoiceCode, ItemCode, (case when LineNum is null then 0 else 1 end), LineNum

_`
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Can you show us some sample data and expected results based on that?

Answer (score 0):

This type of query, with different information on different rows, usually suggests a `union`.  The following is an example of what you probably want:

```
SELECT ci.InvoiceCode, ci.ItemCode,
       NULL as LineNum, S.SourceDocument, 
       s.TrackingNumber, NULL as ActualCost, 
       NULL as ExtActualCost, s.Freight AS FreightCost,
       NULL as SalesPrice, NULL as ExtPrice, 
       NULL as SalesTaxAmount, ci.Freight, 
       ci.FreightTax
FROM Shipment s RIGHT OUTER JOIN
     CustomerInvoice ci
    ON s.SourceDocument = ci.SourceInvoiceCode 
union all
select ci.InvoiceCode, ci.ItemCode,
       cid.LineNum, NULL as SourceDocument, 
       NULL as TrackingNumber, cid.ActualCost, 
       cid.ExtActualCost, NULL AS FreightCost,
       cid.SalesPrice, cid.ExtPrice, 
       cid.SalesTaxAmount, ci.Freight, 
       ci.FreightTax
from CustomerInvoice ci join
     CustomerInvoiceDetail cid
     on ci.InvoiceCode = cid.InvoiceCode
order by InvoiceCode, ItemCode, (case when lineNum is null then 0 else 1 end), LineNum
```

The `case` statement in the `order by` is just to ensure that the row with the NULL LineNum goes first.

Note:  this is untested SQL so it might have syntax errors, particularly with the aliases.

Comment: This makes sense and seems like it should work.  Ill try it shortly.

Might I ask, why call NULL as instead of calling the given fields?

Comment: I see, the first part is pulling just from the invoice/ shipment tables so the columns are selected as null so that it matchs the union below where the values are actually available.

Comment: @user1972492 . . . Exactly.  Or at least they match after the sort implied by the `order by`.

Comment: The Case when LineNum portion (which is a brilliant idea) throws an error that the multipart identifier can not be bound.  I am not sure why since the join above it joins on the customer invoice detail table, and linenum is in that table (also it does not have an issue just calling LineNum, it only has a problem with the case statement.

Comment: @user1972492 . . . That is an odd problem.  There was a problem with the alias on ActualCost in the first half of the query.

Comment: As a work around, i just changed the select statment in the first part to '0' as LineNum, instead of putting a null there and then changing it with a case.


I am however still curious as to why it doesnt accept column labels inside case statements

Comment: @user1972492 . . . Many databases have a "NULL First" or "NULL Last" argument to `order by` -- or something similar.  That also solves the problem.